Blocky light and shadow artifacts all over any lit model rendered in EEVEE

I decided yesterday to start messing with light, low-poly rendering on my very-light-duty college laptop using a DS-game model I ripped a while ago, but I found that the light source that comes with the general startup looks absolutely broken! Blocky shadows fill the entire lit-area of the mesh, irreverent to the strength of light. The thicker shadow blocks seem to follow the wireframe, but for cubed faces, it follows triangulated edges that don't exist on the cube.
I thought it was the .Dae import, but when I actually checked the default cube, it looked exactly the same.
Flipping, recalculating normals doesn't work. Clamping light just removes the light, not the problem. Ambient occlusion doesn't change anything.
Cycles doesn't have this issue, but I didn't want to do thousands of samples per frame on models made in 2008 with fewer polygons than Ghost's left-asscheek.
Replacing the light source (all types cause the problem) with giving the space background texture color (global illumination? I'm not sure what to call it) eliminates the artifacting in the final render, but the material-preview shader for the viewport still has it!
Maybe it has something to do with how EEVEE calculates lighting, and my hardware just can't do it.
I'm on version 4.2.3 LTS

This kind of bug is common with EEVEE in versions from 4.2 and above (they got a new eevee renderer).
While no other solution is known, you can unfortunately stick to Blender 4.1 if you need to use EEVEE.
